# How to fetch data in jquery as input for chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, chart.js

I would like to use chart.js for creating a couple of charts on my webpage, now the data that I receive from the controller is in the following format,

```
{
    "dataset" : [
        {
            "name" : "Sarah",
            "age" : "23",
            "gender" : "female",
            "country" : "australia",
            "occupation" : "student"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Randy",
            "age" : "19",
            "gender" : "male",
            "country" : "america",
            "occupation" : "student"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Roger",
            "age" : "32",
            "gender" : "male",
            "country" : "germany",
            "occupation" : "software professional"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Maverick",
            "age" : "10",
            "gender" : "male",
            "country" : "america",
            "occupation" : "student"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Riya",
            "age" : "25",
            "gender" : "female",
            "country" : "australia",
            "occupation" : "software professional"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Glade",
            "age" : "30",
            "gender" : "female",
            "country" : "India",
            "occupation" : "teacher"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, I would like to plot this information on 3 pie charts,
1) pie chart that shows the count of country of origin.
2) pie chart that shows the count of occupation.
3) pie chart that shows the count of people who have age less than 25.

So ideally the graph takes in information in the following format,

```
var pieData = {
                graph-data: 
                [
                    {
                        name : country,
                        dataset : [
                            {
                                value: america,
                                count: 2,
                                color:"#878BB6"
                            },
                            {
                                value: india,
                                count : 1,
                                color : "#4ACAB4"
                            },
                            {
                                value: germany,
                                count : 1,
                                color : "#FF8153"
                            },
                            {
                                value: australia,
                                count : 2,
                                color : "#FFEA88"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        name : occupation,
                        dataset : [
                            {
                                value: "student",
                                count: 3,
                                color:"#878BB6"
                            },
                            {
                                value: "software professional",
                                count : 2,
                                color : "#4ACAB4"
                            },
                            {
                                value: "teacher",
                                count : 1,
                                color : "#FF8153"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        name : "age",
                        dataset : [
                            {
                                value: "23",
                                count: 1,
                                color:"#878BB6"
                            },
                            {
                                value: "19",
                                count : 1,
                                color : "#4ACAB4"
                            },
                            {
                                value: "10",
                                count : 1,
                                color : "#FF8153"
                            },
                            {
                                value: "25",
                                count : 1,
                                color : "#FF8423"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            };
```

As you can see from the above json, the graph-data key has 3 array elements, each of which corresponds to a chart. How can I construct this data from the initial raw dataset and pass this to my chart.js for consumption? I am guessing I would be requiring to write converters, how can I achieve this in js/jquery, any information on this is highly appreciated. Thanks ahead!

Comment: You are right, you will have to write for loops to parse through the raw dataset to create required format. That is not only easy and stable way to do, but also you will have full control on formatting of json as you are using for chart consumption.

Comment: Start by creating an object with keys `country` , `age` , `occupation`. As you iterate array see if `newobject.ocupation[ocupationValue]` exists. If it doesn't start a counter for that. If it does increment counter. After all that  loop through the new object to build arrays for each `dataset`

Comment: what's the rationale behind the colors color placement?